# Is it possible to run satelize on frontend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Is it possible to run this library on frontend?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/satelize
or, receive user's country code some other way?

what is the benefits of using it instead of direct request:

```
function httpGet() {
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.open( "GET", 'http://www.telize.com/geoip', false ); // false for synchronous request
  xmlHttp.send( null );
  console.log('JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText)', JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText))
  return JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
}
```

Comment: yes, i'm getting error: `g.setTimeout is not a function`